# Two entry table from columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I am trying to create a "two-entry table" from many columns in my `df`. I tried with `pivot_table` / `crosstrab` / `groupby` but results appeareance using this functions is not acomplish since will not be a "two entry table"

for example if i have a dataframe like this :

```
 df
 A  B  C  D  E  
 1  0  0  1  1        
 0  1  0  1  0      
 1  1  1  1  1
```

I will like to transform my df to a df which could be seen like a "two-entry table"

```
   A B C D E
A  2 1 1 2 2
B  1 2 1 2 1 
C  1 1 1 1 1
D  2 2 1 3 1
E  2 1 1 1 2
```

so if i should explain first row, would be as A has two 1 in his column, then A-A = 2, A-B = 1 because they shared one's in the third row level in `df`, A-C = 1 because the third row in `df` they shared one's in the same row level and finaly A-E = 2 because they shared one's in the first row and the third row of `df`

Comment: matrix multiplicaiton: `df.T@df`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.dot` with `T`:

```
df.T.dot(df) # or df.T@df
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
A  2  1  1  2  2
B  1  2  1  2  1
C  1  1  1  1  1
D  2  2  1  3  2
E  2  1  1  2  2
```